# python - Selecting Pandas Columns by dtype

Tags: python, pandas

In dataquest.io the following code returns all int columns. but in jupyter it returns only the int32 column. what goes wrong?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[11,22,33,44,55],'c':[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5]})

df['a'] = df['a'].astype('int')
df['b'] = df['b'].astype('int64')
df['c'] = df['c'].astype('float64')

df
    a   b   c
0   1   11  .1
1   2   22  .2
2   3   33  .3
3   4   44  .4
4   5   55  .5
  int32 int64 float64

int_32 = df.select_dtypes(include=['int'])
```

in dataquest.io the previous code returns:

```
    a   c
0   1   11
1   2   22
2   3   33
3   4   44
4   5   55
```

but in jupyter it returns:

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

dataquest uses pandas 18.0 and I use pandas 20 .what do you think cause this problem?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    5 non-null int32
b    5 non-null int64
c    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int32(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 180.0 bytes

Comment: Can you run `print(np.dtype("int"))` on dataquest.io and Jupyter? It might just be that the default int sizes are different.

Comment: in my pc it returned dtype('int32') but in dataquest it returned dtype('int64')

Comment: Yeah that's probably why only column `a` is getting returned on your machine. Both columns are selected on dataquest.io since `int` and `int64` happened to be the same type. If you want the same columns to be returned consistently then you'd have to use either `int` or specify an integer size explicitly but don't mix both.

Comment: good ti know that

Comment: yeah i got it tnx

Comment: so this is how things works